# Nginx plus Apache .. for Load-balancing?

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I have TWO below simple scenarios to choose which are making me hard to decide:

Scenario (1)

- Load-balancer: `nginx` *(On 1 separated Machine)*
- Web Servers: `Apache` *(On multiple separated Machine)*

Scenario (2)

- Load-balancer: `Apache` *(On 1 separated Machine)*
- Web Servers: `Apache` *(On multiple separated Machine)*

** Lets say i only have `nginx` OR `Apache` only two as the choices. *(No Varnish, etc)*
** Then obviously my question there are:

1. Which one is **better** to load balance the multiple Apache Web Servers?
2. For the Load-balancer, is **NGINX** still **better** then `Apache` (even for the Apache Web Servers below)?

Please kindly help me be adviced.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda a 'what is better' kind of question, which are frowned upon over here. check the [don't ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

I'll tell you one simple thing which is obviously only my personal opinion, nginx is basically a proxy server, so it's built to do this kind of stuff, and it's lighter, so I would recommend nginx as a load balancer instead of apache.